# Import data from SQLite to SQL Server with SqlBulkCopy class

Tags: sqlite, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to transfer the data from SQLite to SQL Server. The schema of target and destination table are just the same:

SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Shop] (
    [ShopID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Url] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ShopID] ASC
))
```

and SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE "Shop" (
    "ShopID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
    "Name" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "Url" VARCHAR NOT NULL);
```

I wrote the code as below (with System.Data.SQLite):

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=Data.sqlite;FailIfMissing=True"))
{ 
    conn.Open();
    var cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Shop", conn);
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Shop";
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ShopID", "ShopID");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Url", "Url");
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
    }
}
```

Data has been loaded by reader (I've checked). But an InvalidOperationException throws on WriteToServer method: The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination.

Any ideas or suggestion for me?

Comment: Am I wrong or this ColumnMappings.Add is not necessary? The two tables are identical...

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not solve your problem, but you probably want to use the SqlBulkCopyOptions to specify that you don't want it to generate new identity values.

```
SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
private void GatherDb3Info(FileInfo[] fiDb3) {
        SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder csb = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
        foreach (FileInfo fi in fiDb3) {
            csb.Clear();
            csb.DataSource = fi.FullName;
            csb.Password = "P@$$w0rd";
            csb.SyncMode = SynchronizationModes.Full;

            using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(csb.ToString())) {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable dtTables = conn.GetSchema(SQLiteMetaDataCollectionNames.Tables, new String[] { });
                foreach (DataRow dRow in dtTables.Rows) {
                    if (dRow["Table_Type"].ToString().ToLower() != "table") continue;
                    String
                        catName = String.Format("{0}", dRow["Table_Catalog"]),
                        schName = String.Format("{0}", dRow["Table_Schema"]),
                        tblName = String.Format("{0}", dRow["Table_Name"]);
                    DataTable dtColumns = conn.GetSchema(SQLiteMetaDataCollectionNames.Columns, new System.String[] { catName, schName, tblName });
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (DataRow dRowColumn in dtColumns.Rows) {
                        sb.AppendFormat("[{0}], ", dRowColumn["Column_Name"]);
                    }

                    String sColList = sb.ToString();
                    sColList = sColList.Remove(sColList.Length - 2);
                    var cmd = new SQLiteCommand("Select " + sColList + " From " + tblName, conn);
                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    using (var bulkCopy = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(@"Server=.;Integrated Security=true;Database=TargetDBName;")) {
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TargetTableSchema." + tblName;
                        try {
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                        } catch (Exception) { }
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That empty catch block is going to give you a big headache if there is an error and you don't know it. Maybe that's why you are saying "it works". Who knows?