# How can I make use of a .db file in SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, sqlite, odbc

I have access to a .db file that I would like to query somehow to pull data from it for my other database.  So far I have been unable to do this through an ODBC or SQL server directly.  I would think that this is possible but I can't seem to find any ideas how.

Comment: Hello @user3728545 is there any correct solution for your question, I have also stuck in a similar situation  where i want to open a .db file

Answer (score 5):

.db files are standalone files, so cannot be Opened through SSMS. 
Use [SQLITE DB BROWSER](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitedbrowser/) to work on those files. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

.db files are standalone files, which means they don't need server to work, which also means you can't open it with SQL Server 2008.
More more info check [THIS LINK](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/db)

Comment: So if SQL Server can't open a .db file, then how can we open it, I also have a .db file that I would like to open. Please help me, how can i view its structure?

Answer (score 3):

If this is a one time load, the easiest option would be using the SQL Server Import and Export wizard from SSMS. You'll need a Sqlite ODBC driver. The one [here](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) should work.

Another option is to create a linked server to SQLite database from SQL Server. See [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3087/creating-a-sql-server-linked-server-to-sqlite-to-import-data/) for instructions.

Here are a couple of StackOverflow posts on loading data from Sqlite to SQL Server which might be helpful.

- [Bulk load tables in SQLite db files into SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138788/bulk-load-tables-in-sqlite-db-files-into-sql-server)
- [Import data from SQLite to SQL Server with SqlBulkCopy class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333592/import-data-from-sqlite-to-sql-server-with-sqlbulkcopy-class)