# Upload .db file to Azure SQL

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have a .db file, with a bunch of tables and data (and a few one to many relationships), instead of rewriting everything, is there a way for me to just upload this database directly to Azure SQL?

Comment: what have you tried now? Or did you  upload the .db file to Azure SQL successfully before?

Comment: Just as I know, .db files are standalone files, there isn't a way which can  upload this database directly to Azure SQL. Maybe you could reference this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962255/how-can-i-make-use-of-a-db-file-in-sql-server-2008 to get some workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to install SQL Server Developer Edition on your laptop or local computer and import those database files to that SQL instance as explained h[ere](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2463/importing-dbf-files-into-sql-server/), if they are Dbase files.

Once you have imported the .dbf files to the local SQL Server instance, use [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) to deploy the database to Azure as shown [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3035/using-the-deploy-database-to-sql-azure-wizard-in-sql-server-management-studio-to-move-to-the-cloud/) and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5255/learn-how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-sql-azure-server/), or you can use [Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) to migrate to Azure as explained [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5443/use-data-migration-assistant-dma-to-migrate-onpremises-sql-server-database-to-azure/).